# Copying directory and files from one windows server to another

Tags: java, windows, file

From a WindowsServer, I am using:

```
File src = new File("\\\\servername\\D:\\LogFiles");
```

When I check for `src.isDirectory()`, it says false. Tried a different directory but again it returns false. Checked and the directories exists in the other Windows Server.

Most probably, it seems the issue is with the slashes. can someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
File src = new File("\\\\servername\\D$\\LogFiles");
```

1. Using $ for drivers.
2. Add add \ for all "\" characters.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure part of the problem is a windows share won't have a colon in it "D:"
If you are trying to access the admin share for the D drive you'd need to use "D$"